# Apply Require Check Out Feature to all available sites' libraries

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, check-out, bulk

I have a task to enable the 'Require Check Out' feature on each document library on all sites we have. See the picture below:

[image]

There are about 20 sites in our site collection and each site has only one document library where I need to enable the feature. Is there any bulk option to change the feature for all libraries at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it with PowerShell script.It is having attribute `$list.ForceCheckout = $true`

for more reference you can refer this [Change SharePoint list settings using PowerShell - Part 1: General and Versioning](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/changing-sharepoint-list-settings-using.html)

Please let me know if it help you.

Thanks

Comment: I actually did it manually already :) But the article is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use below PowerShell command to set **Require Check Out** feature on each document library on all sites

```
    foreach ($web in (Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All))
         {
            Write-Host “Processing Web: $($web.Url)…”
            foreach ($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]}))
            {
    $list.ForceCheckout = $true;
    $list.Update();

   }
```